# CALCULATING TIME in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using this formula to calculate time between 2 different fields but result is in whole numbers and I need hours/minutes

time after dateFromString is example

```js
var date1 = dateFromString(06: 00: 00);
var date2 = dateFromString(17: 30: 00);
var hours = Math.abs(date1 - date2) / 36e5;
return hours;

function dateFromString(isoDateString) {
  var parts = isoDateString.match(/\d+/g);
  var isoTime = Date.UTC(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]);
  var isoDate = new Date(isoTime);
  return isoDate;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the current output using `console.log()`.

Comment: You're missing quotes around the argument to `dateFromString()`.

Comment: You can't have a `return hours` statement outside a function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some syntax errors, but try this, it should give you the time difference in an hours:minutes format:

```js
var startTime = '06:00:00';
var endTime = '17:30:00';
var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + startTime);
var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2007 " + endTime);

var minutesDiff = diff_minutes(timeStart, timeEnd);
var hoursAndMinsDiff = convertMinsToHrsMins(minutesDiff);

console.log(hoursAndMinsDiff)

function diff_minutes(dt2, dt1) {
    var diff = (dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / 1000;
    diff /= 60;
    return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));
}

function convertMinsToHrsMins(mins) {
    let h = Math.floor(mins / 60);
    let m = mins % 60;
    h = h < 10 ? '0' + h : h;
    m = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m;
    return `${h}:${m}`;
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Use division to get the hours, and then get the minutes using the remainder operation.

Also, `dateFromString()` expects the string to have both the date and time, not just a time, and it needs to be a quoted string.

```js
var date1 = dateFromString("2018-12-01 06:00:00");
var date2 = dateFromString("2018-11-30 17:30:00");
var diffmin = Math.floor(Math.abs(date1 - date2) / 60000);
var hours = Math.floor(diffmin/60);
var minutes = diffmin % 60;
console.log(hours, minutes);

function dateFromString(isoDateString) {
  var parts = isoDateString.match(/\d+/g);
  var isoTime = Date.UTC(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]);
  var isoDate = new Date(isoTime);
  return isoDate;
}
```